# Java RegEx check for one or more formatted strings

Tags: java, regex

Sorry if the title isn't descriptive enough.
I want to be able to extract into a group if a specificly formatted sequence occurs one or more times.

Here is my current REGEX-> (removed duplicate slashes for clarity)

**(.*?):([A-Z\d]{3}-[A-Z\d]{5}-[A-Z\d]{2})(:[A-Z\d]{3}-[A-Z\d]{5}-[A-Z\d]{2}).***

I know I'm close but not quite there.

So these are valid

**TEST1:001-12345-67:ABC-DEFGH-IJ**

returned as **TEST1 , 001-12345-67 , :ABC-DEFGH-IJ** (commas separate groups)

**WHATEVER:123-12345-12:987-98765-98:ASD-ASDFA-AS**  (current regex doesn't work for this)

returned as **WHATEVER , 123-12345-12 , :987-98765-98:ASD-ASDFA-AS**

And these aren't

**TEST1:001-12345-67**

**WHATEVER:123-12345-12:HMMMM**

It's like I need to do a bracket with a '.' for the whole second sequence.  Thanks for everyone's contemplation.  PS Regex make my head hurt.

Comment: Have you tried the Regex plugin for IntelliJ IDEA?  It's genius.

Comment: Could you please clarify the pattern you are trying to match for us?

Comment: No i have not.  I'm using Netbeans IDE.

Comment: @jjnguy, i mentioned the pattern in acceptable inputs.  But in the end, I want 3 groups.  the first matching the generic text input, the scond being that 3 sectioned hyphenated part, and the last being the rest of the string assuming there is at least one of that string format ( :XXX-XXXXX-XX )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
/(.*?(?::[A-Z\d]{3}-[A-Z\d]{5}-[A-Z\d]{2}){2,})/
```

And then split the captured text on the ":" to get the separate chunks.

EDIT: Wait, you just want three chunks regardless of how many groups there are? That's pretty easy. You could get it by calling `split(':', 3)` (rather than just `split(':')` on the results of the above, or go for the regex solution:

```
/(.*?):([A-Z\d]{3}-[A-Z\d]{5}-[A-Z\d]{2})((?::[A-Z\d]{3}-[A-Z\d]{5}-[A-Z\d]{2})+)/
```

(The third group will start with an extra ":" that you don't want, that can be removed if you don't mind bloating the pattern even more):

```
/(.*?):([A-Z\d]{3}-[A-Z\d]{5}-[A-Z\d]{2}):([A-Z\d]{3}-[A-Z\d]{5}-[A-Z\d]{2}(?::[A-Z\d]{3}-[A-Z\d]{5}-[A-Z\d]{2})*)/
```

Comment: i thought about just accepting anything after the second colon and then parsing that separately.  The second portion would then need to be checked for validity and if it doesn't pass, pop out and continue as if it didn't match originally.

Comment: @NickG: But you can easily check it for validity in just the one regex.

Comment: That looks to be working.  Thanks alot.  I'll mark it as answered after some additional testing.  Thanks